# How to minimize beam walk off during quarter wave plate roration

Tags: optics, microscopy, nanoscience

I am currently building a laser scanning microscope setup. I need to focus the laser on my sample and also place a quarter-wave plate right before the sample so I can control the polarization of the light. Right now I am having a hard time figuring out the solution to the beam drift during continuously rotating the quarter-wave plate. Can anyone give some idea about what should I do?

Comment: what do you mean beam drifting?

Comment: I mean the beam spot position changes

Comment: If the beam were exactly perpendicular to the waveplate, it wouldn’t change. If it is, refraction is happening from the beam hitting the optic at an angle.